# Avoiding try-catch-finally hell

Tags: java, coding-style

let say I have simple connection and select from database. Sadness part of this code is that almost let say 40-50% is try-catch boilerplate code. How can I deal with it?

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test",
                    "root",
                    "root"
            );
            statement = connection.createStatement();

            String sql = "SELECT id, name from user";
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");

                System.out.print("ID: " + id);
                System.out.print(", name: " + name);
                System.out.println();
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
         
            try {
                if (statement != null)
                    statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException ignored) {
            }
            try {
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The way to avoid try-catch-finally hell is to use try-with-resources.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: you can make the method `throw SQLException`

Comment: @AP11 that just moves the problem one step above in the chain of methods or (in this case, since we're talking about the `main` method) just makes the program crash ungracefully. Ideally, you never want your user to see a stack trace.

Comment: But that doesn't cure the other problems in your code; e.g. catching `Exception` is a usually a mistake, printing stacktraces in a exception handler is usually a mistake, etc.  (An easily guessable password on your database is probably a mistake :-) )  OK so this looks like throw away code, so these things may be excusable in this context ...

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I know, I am not saying it's a good solution, but since it's only main method then it might be suitable solution to avoid those 2 try-catch statements.

Comment: @AP11 have your main method throw an Exception is never a suitable solution.

Answer (score 2):

The way to avoid *try-catch-finally* hell is to use *try-with-resources*.  It was added to the Java language in Java 7.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html for a more detailed explanation of this Java language feature.

Here's what your code looks like with try-with-resources

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception /* bad idea */ {
    String sql = "SELECT id, name from user";   
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test",
                "root",
                "root");
         Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql))
    {
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String name = rs.getString("name");

            System.out.print("ID: " + id);
            System.out.print(", name: " + name);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the *try-with-resources* will automatically close each of the declared resources (`connection`, `statement` and `rs`) in the reverse order that they were declared, and will deal *appropriately* with any exceptions that may arise during that.  So we don't need any explicit `close()` calls.

If this was production code, we should NOT declare `main` as throwing exceptions.  We should be dealing with the exceptions properly; i.e. logging them and/or producing a user friendly error message.  I'm just taking a shortcut here ... because that's a side-bar to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code cleaner with try-with-resources, like that-

```
        try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test",
                "root",
                "root"
        );Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
         
            String sql = "SELECT id, name from user";
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");

                System.out.print("ID: " + id);
                System.out.print(", name: " + name);
                System.out.println();
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It'll handle closing resources. For details go to [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 1):

## `DataSource`

Set up a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) object with all your connection details such as username and password. Your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) likely comes with a simple implementation.

```java
SomeDataSourceImplementation ds = new SomeDataSourceImplementation() ;
ds.setUserName( "Scott" ) ;
ds.setPassword( "Tiger" ) ;
…
DataSource dataSource = ds ;
```

## Try-with-resources syntax

The *try-with-resources* syntax was added years ago to help simplify such code. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

If an exception is thrown, the [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) objects are closed in the reverse order in which they were listed.

```
        String sql = "SELECT id, name from user";
        try (
            Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement() ;
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql) ;
        ) {
            while ( rs.next() ) {
                int id = rs.getInt( "id" ) ;
                String name = rs.getString( "name" ) ;

                System.out.print( "ID: " + id );
                System.out.print( ", name: " + name ) ;
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```